# How fast do the war chests unlock?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've read what I can find about the war chest, and it says

> "Each War Chest begins with a single unit skin and an exclusive portrait. Play Multiplayer or Co-op matches to earn experience and unlock the rest of the set, along with emoticons and an upgraded portrait."

But I can't find anything about how much experience it takes. Does coop experience count? About how many games am I going to have to play in total?

Answer (score 2):

"War Chest starts with an initial content unlock: a StarCraft II portrait and worker skin for each race you purchase, a Heroes Loot Chest, a Hearthstone Card Pack, and an exclusive Diablo probe pet. Each additional node unlock occurs for every 300,000 XP earned, and successively adds content. For reference, the bonus experience received for your first win of the day in multiplayer awards 100,000 XP per race. Thus, it’s possible to unlock a node in a single day by winning one match as each race". - Blizzard

Comment: This looks awesome. What's the source on that?

Comment: Heyyyy, my exclusive Probe pet for buying LotV Deluxe just got a little less exclusive :-)